# How to rectify database restore error in odoo12?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I have got the following error while restoring a database with attachments in odoo12.

I created a python virtual environment and installed odoo12 within the virtual environment and tried to restore a database. But the same error also occurs in the virtual environment also.

```
hrms_db_1 odoo.sql_db: bad query: INSERT INTO "ir_attachment" ("id", "create_uid", "create_date", "write_uid", "write_date", "active", "company_id", "datas_fname", "mimetype", "name", "public", "res_id", "res_model", "type") VALUES (nextval('ir_attachment_id_seq'), 1, (now() at time zone 'UTC'), 1, (now() at time zone 'UTC'), true, 1, 'web.assets_common.js', 'application/javascript', '/web/content/js', true, 0, 'ir.ui.view', 'binary') RETURNING id 
ERROR: relation "ir_attachment_id_seq" does not exist LINE 1: ...", "res_id", "res_model", "type") VALUES (nextval('ir_attach...
```

Comment: Which IDE is you are using? Pycharm?

Comment: To me, it seems like the database was not correctly backed up. Did you back it up manually or using Odoo? In the latter case, the zip file contains the filestore dir and a SQL file which can be restored manually using `psql` to check if the sequence `ir_attachment_id_seq` exists and diagnose the problem.

Comment: Yes I am using Pycharm as my IDE.I tried to backup using odoo and psql also

Comment: Make sure you are using same Odoo and postgres versions.

Answer (score 2):

From https://github.com/Yenthe666/auto_backup/issues/79#issuecomment-420711666

Issue was because of different postgres versions on Odoo & Database server. Postgres 9.x vs 10

- Apparently there is a single statement that causes this when creating sequences, which is the "AS INTEGER" in every "CREATE SEQUENCE" which is not supported in PostgreSQL 9.6.
  To work around this, you need to unzip your backup file, open & edit your dump.sql file and delete every occurrence of "AS INTEGER" from every "CREATE SEQUENCE" statement. Then zip the contents again and try to restore one more time. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the Python Interpreter you assigned is the right one, means virtual env.[image]

Also, check the connectivity with the database and the odoo and custom addons folder permissions too.